# TRIGGER INSERT last row into one of the chosen tables if WHERE conditions are true

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am currentlty using triggers in a table to copy the last row into a designated table based on a WHERE condition and ORDER BY. Using one trigger works fine and copies to the respective table. but both triggers are running causing duplicates of a previous row to appear in the table I dont want inserted. (SQL2008 Management Studio). I have specific tables to send this row too based on the partnumber. Here is the Structure:

```
ALTER TRIGGER NewT3650 ON JD_Passdata
FOR INSERT 
AS
INSERT T3_650_TestData (SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc)
SELECT TOP 1 SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc
FROM JD_Passdata
WHERE partnumber = 'T3_650'
ORDER BY passdata_ndx DESC

ALTER TRIGGER NewT4450 ON JD_Passdata
FOR INSERT 
AS
INSERT T4_450_TestData (SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc)
SELECT TOP 1 SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc
FROM JD_Passdata
WHERE partnumber = 'T4_450'
ORDER BY passdata_ndx DESC
```

Original PassData Table:

```
201244999, T4_450
201245001, T3_650
201245002, T3_650
201245003, T3_650
```

Returns Results for table 1

```
201245001, T3_650
201245002, T3_650
201245003, T3_650
```

Returns Results for table 2

```
201244999, T4_450
201244999, T4_450
201244999, T4_450
```

I would like this to be an OR condition or a UNION that only takes the last row and enters it into the correct table and remove the additional trigger if possible. Otherwise a check for duplicate and update may do it too. Also the database is going to get quite large to do a DESC every entry may get slow. A method to remove the order by would be a consideration as well.

Any sugesstions would be greatly appreciated...THX

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works for both triggers but may be causing a problem when a "NULL" result occurs. It does get rid of the ORDER BY and may be faster. What this does is use the unique last row index number as the row location and checks the part number to determine an insert into the new table. Also, when I add a third trigger using this same format for a different table the initial move to the main table (JD_PassData) fails. Not sure why yet.

Here is the new code:

ALTER TRIGGER NewT3650 ON JD_Passdata
AFTER INSERT 
AS
INSERT T3_650_TestData (SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc)
SELECT SerialNumber, Partnumber, etc
FROM JD_Passdata
WHERE passdata_ndx=(SELECT MAX(passdata_ndx) FROM JD_PassData) AND PartNumber = 'T3_650'